# How to avoid the php function call when passing a function variable?

Tags: php, function, parameters

I have a function variable like this...

```
$aName = "My Name";
```

The function need to pass in like this:

```
$sayHelloFunction = function sayHello($aName){
       echo($aName);
}
```

Than, I have a method that responsible for execute the sayHelloFunction:

```
runningFunction($sayHelloFunction($aName));
```

in the runningFunction, it will have some condition to execute the function, but when I pass the "$sayHelloFunction($aName)" to runningFunction, it execute automatically, but I would like to pass the variable  $aName as well, how can I achieve it? Thank you.

Comment: i think you are confusing php and javascript

Comment: @Ibrahim - this is a perfectly valid PHP question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass the arguments separately. However, you could wrap them in an array so that you can pass them to `runningFunction` as a single argument, like this:

```
$printFunction = function($args) {
    print $args['lastname'].', '.$args['firstname'];
};

function runningFunction($f, $a) {
    $f($a);
}

$firstname = 'Bob';
$lastname = 'Smith';

$functionArguments = array(
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'lastname' => $lastname
);

runningFunction($printFunction, $functionArguments);
```

<strike>If you want your dynamic functions to get "proper" arguments, then I see no way around something like this:</strike>

```
function runningFunction($f, $a) {
    switch(count($a)) {
        0: $f(); break;
        1: $f($a[0]); break;
        2: $f($a[0], $a[1]); break;
        3: $f($a[0], $a[1], $a[2]); break;
        // and so on
    }
}
```

Comment: `call_user_func_array()` basically does what you did in your `switch` statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
runningFunction($sayHelloFunction, $aName);
```

Simples.

Comment: but my sayHelloFunction requires param, and I don't want to assign the param inside the runningFunction.....

Answer (score 1):

Pass the parameters as an array, and then use `call_user_func_array()` to call your function.

This way your `runningFunction()` will be absolutely abstract (as you requested), it can call any type of function, it's your responsibility to pass the right number of parameters.

```
function runningFunction ($callback, $parameters=array()) {
    call_user_func_array($callback, $parameters);
}

runningFunction($sayHelloFunction, array($aName));
```

[call_user_func_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

as xconspirisist suggested pass `$aName` as a seperate parameter to the function.

Details on [Variable Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) can be found on the PHP site.

Comment: I want to make the runningFunction abstract, that don't depends on the $sayHelloFunction, I don't mind pass runningFunction one more param, but I am considering, if I have one more param require, like $sayHelloFunctionAgain, which requires two params, $aName, $aTime, then, I need to write one more params for runningFunction, that is not wt I want....

Answer (score 0):

Use an anonymous function when calling `runningFunction`

```
function runningFunction($func) {
    $func();
}

runningFunction(function() {
    $sayHelloFunction($aName));
    // You can do more function calls here...
});
```